# How can i get the class of a div by clicking another div?

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have 2 div,in both the div i have the same id but different class. When clicked on one div we can get its attribute id.its ok.. This id is same for the other div. How can i get the class of this 2nd div using this id?

```
<div class="oneclass" id="same">Hi this is the first div</div>
<div class="secondclass" id="same">Hi This is the second div</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("div.secondclass").click(function () {
         pos=$(this).attr('id');
         alert("the id of the 2nd div is ="+pos);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the two `<div>` elements have the same `class` but different `id`s?

Comment: Don't create elements with the same ids.  Those are supposed to be unique on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have two elements with the same id like that.  That is an invalid HTML document and any DOM inspection/manipulation relying on duplicated id attributes is likely going to have unpredictable results across different browsers.

That said, if I had to quickly and roughly edit your above code to do what you're asking, I'd end up with something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="firstclass" id="firstid">Hi this is the first div</div>
<div class="secondclass" id="secondid">Hi This is the second div</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("div.secondclass").click(function () {
         firstclass=$('#firstid').attr('class');
         alert("the class of the 1st div is ="+firstclass);
        });
</script>
```

There may be a more succinct and/or more typically jQuery way to do it than the jQuery above, but the above works and is close enough to your initial code that you should be able to follow the changes very easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how can i solve this...? How can i get the class of div1 by clicking div2 if am having a different id..??

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, two different elements are not allowed to have the same `id`. Give the second div a different `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Can i get the other way...??same class and different id to get the class of div1 by clicking div2..??